# Get Element By Class in codeceptJS with WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, codeceptjs

Please how can I get element by class attribute using codeceptjs & WebDriver?
This is my element, I wanna get `TEST` as value

```
<div data-v-f0eb3906="" class="category_label pl-2 pr-2" xpath="1">TEST</div>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: <div data-v-f0eb3906="" class="category_label pl-2 pr-2" xpath="1">TEST</div> this is my element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the class names `category_label pl-2 pr-2` are unique, you can locate this element with XPath

```
//div[@class='category_label pl-2 pr-2']
```

or with CSS selector

```
div.category_label.pl-2.pr-2
```

But if `category_label pl-2 pr-2` class names are dynamically changing or not unique you will have to define locator in dependence of some parent element.